# Update particular field of a table from values of Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two tables : The first table is this :-
[image: Table 1]

From this table I want to **SUM** only week3 info i.e the **pointsRewarded** and **Hours** field into the below table's **TotalPoints** and **TotalHours** field.

i already have the tables created.I just want to update the below table.

[image]

Please help me with the query or give me some suggestions on how to solve this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: i want to update the second table..

Comment: duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server

Comment: Please always remember to Google first before asking a question on Stack Overflow. A query for `update table from other table` sqlserver will turn up dozens of answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to guess that the first table already exists and you want to add in the week 3 values:

```
update t2
    set pointsrewarded = t1.pointsrewarded + t2.pointsrewarded,
        hours = t1.hours + t2.hours
    from t2 join
         (select t1.employeeid, sum(pointsrewarded) as pointsrewarded
                 sum(hours) as hours, 
          from t1
          where t1.weeknumber = 'week3'
          group by t1.employeeid
         ) t1
         on t2.employeeid = t1.employeeid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] (
    [EmployeeID]
    ,[Employee Name]
    ,[TotalPoints]
    ,[TotalHours]
    )
SELECT  
    [EmployeeID]
    ,[Employee Name]
    ,SUM(pointRewarded) as [TotalPoints]
    ,SUM([Hours]) as [TotalHours]
FROM [dbo].[Table1]
WHERE WeekNumber='week3'
GROUP BY   
    [EmployeeID]
    ,[Employee Name]

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cte` in this situation .

```
;WITH cte_1
         as (SELECT employeeid
                   ,SUM(pointsrewarded) as Week3TotalPoints
                   ,SUM([hours]) as Week3TotalHours
              FROM YourSourceTable  
              WHERE WeekNumber = 'week3'
              GROUP BY employeeid)
        UPDATE d
        SET d.TotalPoints=d.TotalPoints+c.Week3TotalPoints,
            d.TotalHours=d.TotalHours+c.Week3TotalHours
        FROM cte_1 c
         JOIN YourDestinationTable d on c.employeeid=d.employeeid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE table2 
SET    totalpoints = totalpoints+(SELECT Sum(E.pointrewarded) 
                      FROM   table1 E 
                      WHERE  E.weeknumber = 'week3' 
                             AND E.employeeid = employeeid), 
       totalhours = totalhours+(SELECT Sum(E.hours) 
                     FROM   table1 E 
                     WHERE  E.weeknumber = 'week3' 
                            AND E.employeeid = employeeid)
```